# Including header file with global variable

Tags: c++, linker

I need to include a header file that contains some global variables (not mine so I cannot change it).

How do I do this so that the variables within the included file are considered 'extern' in all but one case?

Comment: Does "contain" mean "declare" or "define"?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Copy the header and add extern yourself.

Comment: It's kind of nonstandard for header files to be written the way you describe for just this reason.  Normally you'd want the header file to have every global declared with `extern`, and then have the actual variable storage declarations made in an implementation file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are only declared in the header, but aren't assigned a value, then you might be able to do this, depending on the compiler. GCC, for example, has the -fno-common flag to control this behavior.